# Spring integration-graph: It is posible to show components within profiles or imports?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm used to work with a spring-context.xml with a "beans" root tag, where I write the whole app configuration. That way, I can see integration-graph from STS 3.6.4.
Now I want to divide some components of my app for testing purposes. First, I tried to separe the different components and create different componentX-spring-context.xml confiuguration files for each group of components of the system, and then import all of them from my main spring-context.xml. However, I could not see the integration-graph anymore.

Now I'm trying to divide the components creating multiple spring profiles, which I could use for testing. This is a cleaner way than working with multiple context files. But the problem is the same: I cannot see any of my component which are within some beans profile element, indeed I cannot see any component which are not directly on my "beans" root element, not even if the profile is "default". This is, only the components which are direct children of "beans" element are shown in the integration-graph. And obviously I cannot create multiple  elements, since there must be only one root XML element.

Is there any way to configure STS to show components belonging to some profile?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time; the graph doesn't handle profiles or `<import/>`s.